# Disabling MTP/PTP/all USB stuff except charging

Tags: usb, cyanogenmod

Is there a way to disable all USB functionality except for charging? I don't really use MTP or PTP and would like to disable it if possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to Settings → Storage and tap on the overflow menu in the top right (on a device with a physical menu key, you may need to press that instead). This should bring up a menu item labeled "USB Computer Connection":

[image]

Tap on that, and it will give you a list with possible connection modes. Uncheck everything that you don't intend to use. On my N5/CM11 there are only two options on this page: MTP and PTP. Unchecking both causes the phone to simply charge when plugged into a PC. I have seen others that have an explicit "Charge Only" option, but I believe that is nonstandard.

Comment: Note also that PTP must be ticked for tethering to be offered, either via USB or Bluetooth.

Comment: @andybjackson That has not been my experience at all. I never use PTP, but I certainly use USB tethering from time to time. Also seems odd that tethering over Bluetooth (a wireless protocol) would somehow depend on PTP.

Comment: If I untick both, ADB stops working as well (LG P880 running CM11/Android 4.4). If one of them is ticked, I always get two popups on my PC when connecting the cable (asking to mount the MTP storage). Drives me crazy. Whish there were an explicit "charge only" as it was with "older versions".

Comment: @Izzy They actually ended up adding "charge only" to AOSP in 6.0, and made it the default: http://www.androidcentral.com/inside-marshmallow-usb-connection-options

Comment: I'd be happy with that default actually (if it works, see: [“adb devices” gives “no permission” when on charge-only](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/128609/16575)) – but I agree the user should be able to chose what fits *him/her* best.

Comment: Clicking that just say "Usb is now disconnected". Clicking it again says the same thing.

Comment: On a Samsung Galaxy S5, this option is located at Settings → System → Developer options → Debugging → Networking → USB configuration.  Change it from "MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)" to "Charging".

Answer (score 10):

The most device-compatible way to disable *everything* is to run this command at startup or set this in your build.prop:

```
setprop persist.sys.usb.config none
```

which is equivalent to **charge-only** on *all* Android devices.

That also disables adb. If you use adb regularly, then:

```
setprop persist.sys.usb.config adb
```

will allow adb when developer options are turned on/checked. If you don't use ADB often, I would not recommend it, because setting `adb` causes my S5 to still recognize in device manager, even when it is locked.

To restore original functionality,

```
setprop persist.sys.usb.config mtp,ptp,adb
```

allows all USB protocols.

Hope this helps anyone Googling for an answer.

Comment: Have you verified that these commands would work without root access?

Comment: People who have custom recovery can apply a changed `build.prop` without root. Those who have locked bootloaders & no recovery will need root permissions.

Comment: On Android 5.1.1 (CyanogenOS 12 on a Wileyfox Swift), using `setprop persist.sys.usb.config adb` lets `adb devices` show `????????????    no permissions`. Played with all combinations – no way to get "charge only + adb". Must be "x,adb" (with x=mtp or ptp) to work at all. To restore, in terminal I needed root. The notification menu just grayed out when I tried re-enabling MTP from there.

Comment: even if it's not in startup it works, and it even persists between reboots. (becuase of the persist.xxx.yyy.zzz thanks

Answer (score 0):

- click 5 times  on **SETTINGS>ABOUT PHONE>MODEL NUBMER**
- then **DEVELOPER OPTIONS** will be added in main settings (in bottom). Enter there and choose **USB SETTINGS> CHARGING|MTP.**

([Source](http://en.code-bude.net/2013/03/05/how-to-activate-usb-mass-storage-and-developer-options-on-cyanogenmod-10-1/))