# Is there a way to remove all other USB options except charging?

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode

Is there a way to disable *MTP/PTP* and all *other* USB options except *Charging* option from the Android system?

I'm using LG G4 beat, Android 5.1.1 and i want to **remove** it for my new ROM that i working on

Rooted device

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give abit more information (device make/model, OS, is rooted, etc.)? Also, why do you want to remove these capabilities?

Comment: Additional to that: Do you really want to *remove* (title), or are you just annoyed by the "drive-found" popups everytime you connect your device? What have you already checked/tried then?

Comment: Related: [Disabling MTP/PTP/all USB stuff except charging](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/70225/16575) / [Can I disable MTP mode and just have a regular USB connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/21854/16575) / [“adb devices” gives “no permission” when on charge-only](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/128609/16575)

Comment: If you really want to **remove** these modes, the easisest method would be to edit the boot.img's ramdisk, which has a file xxxxxxx.usb.rc and remove the modes. If you want to remove those options from settings, edit the Settings.apk using APKtool

Answer (score 0):

There no action to disabling MTP mode, but you'll make remove all USB option is: connecting to electrical plug, not the PC.